# Linq OrderBy sort rule

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sorting

I want to know on which rule the OrderBy method of Linq decides on how to sort a list of chars. I thought that it compares the char to each other with the help of the values they have in the Ascii table, but I tried it by myself an it was not correct. So does somebody know on which rule the sort is done?

**EDIT:**

```
 string[] letters = { " ", "!", "+", "1", "9", "?", "A", "B", "Y", "Z", "[", "a", "b", "y", "z", "{"};
 IEnumerable<string> ascending = letters.OrderBy(x => x);
 // returns { " ", "!", "?", "[", "{", "+", "1", "9", "a", "A", "b", "B", "y", "Y", "z", "Z"}
```

I expexted to receive the same list back, but I got it with a complete new order.

**SOLUTION:**
I used a string array instead of a char array, so the OrderBy sorted the strings which is different than when you use chars.

Comment: can you add your example and what you've expected ?

Comment: Could you just turn the brightness up on your screen a little? It's a bit hard to see the code you've already tried...

Comment: @GeoffJames but ... I thought if you turn the brightness up, the dim questions disappear ... :)

Comment: Haha. Very clever @Noctis :) That might not be such a bad idea, after all - in this instance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is ordering it fine. It is ordering it by the way it compares `string` (it is a `string[]`). If you want it to do it by the ASCII values of `char` it should be a `char[]` and not a `string[]`:

```
char[] letters = { ' ', '!', '+', '1', '9', '?', 'A', 'B', 'Y', 'Z', '[', 'a', 'b', 'y', 'z', '{', ' ', '!', '+', '1', '9' };
var descending = letters.OrderByDescending(x => x).ToList();
```

And also by the name of the variable I guess you want the `OrderByDescending` method instead.

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason you want to keep using strings, but don't want the default culture sensitive comparison, you can force an "ASCII" sort by adding the `IComparer` parameter to the call to `OrderBy`, and specifying that you want the comparison to use the code point values for sorting:

```
letters.OrderBy(x => x, StringComparer.Ordinal);
```

Answer (score 0):

Two characters are compared by their ASCII or Unicode value.

ASCII table: http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/american-standard-code-information-interchange/ascii-codes-table.png

So ('A' is 65) is considered greater than ('a' is 97) b'coz 65 comes BEFORE 97.
You can lookup ASCII code of each character in your array in the table above.
(And your array should be "char[] letters" not "string[] letters" from what I can see :D)

Comment: that was my problem, i overlooked that i was using kind of a wrong datatype for my usage.